How to clean a messy data in a column in csv file with python or Power BI
I am working on a dashboard to show employees (technicians on the field) productive working hours.
I have a CSV file exported from the app that the technicians use when they are executing their tasks. The column that I actually need and contains the working hours for each task is filled by the technicians on the field in a way that is super hard to extract the actual working hours. So for example the column is filled with values such as:
1 hour. 25 minutes

2h. 22m

2hours for each technician

1 hour for technician x and 2 hours for technician y

12:00 - 13:40

from 12 till 15

and so on
The dataset contains more that 10.000 rows
I have tried different things with Power BI and Python, but it is really hard to find one solution to clean the column with all these possibilities in which the times are mentioned.
Do you guys have any suggestions, ideas on how to go about it? What would you do? Any ideas or suggestions for my issue would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.


Hi @Abdul, and welcome to the StackOverflow community!!! The first thing that comes to mind is to identify all possible ways in which technicians may report the hours. Have you done so already? Are all these possibilities the ones you report in your question? If not, could you edit your question to include them? Once you have this sorted, I will be able to help you (I've got different ideas on how to approach your problem, but they depend on the range and format of the reported hours).

Also, it would be great if you could provide us with a link to the file (if you are allowed to do so).

I'm a bit reluctant to recommend this, but this but this kind of language problem is fairly well handled in many cases by an LLM. For example, chatGPT will tell you that the number of minutes in "2h. 22m" is 142.

@anmabe Thanks a lot. Unfortunately I can't really share the file. I will upload a screenshot as an example for the values in that column (it is in German)

@JonSG thanks. I actually passed the column to chatGPT and it seems to return the desired results. maybe I can build a solution around this

We can see, from the image you provided, that time may be reported in one of the following main formats:

A. X,X or X (followed by  , h, std, stunde, stunden)
B. X (followed by min or minuten)
C. XX:XX - YY:YY or X bis Y

There are also other lines that attempt to concatenate the above formats:

I.   Adding a + sign to indicate multiple tasks (time is, nonetheless, indicated using one of [1] or [2] formats)
II.   Concatenating formats (A) and (B) together (i.e., 1 Stunden und 40 Minuten)

The best approach, after having identified these possibilities is to create an algorithm yourself to translate all timestamps into HH:MM format. The following outline should help you construct it:

Define three regex that match patterns (A), (B), and (C)

Define a function timeExtracter() that performs the following logic, given an input funkyTime:

Remove all spaces and convert all uppercase letters into lowercase (this should make the regex expressions simpler)
If pattern (C) is matched, extract the numbers and subtract the times (this will already be in HH:MM format).
If pattern (A) is matched, convert the decimal time into HH:MM format.
If pattern (B) is matched, extract the number MM and construct a 00:MM timestamp.
if no pattern is matched, store the line somewhere to be manually reviewed, and continue the execution normally (This will rarely occur, but it is best to treat exceptions this way, rather than waving out code break).


Iterate through every line in the CSV and apply the following logic:

If the time includes concatenating operators (namely, und or +), separate the timestamp into two at the position of the operator and call timeExtracter() with each portion. Then add them up, and you will have the timestamp. Store it somewhere, and break the iteration of the loop to continue with the next line in the CSV file.
Else: call timeExtracter() with the entire line.



Since the file you have cannot be accessed, I could not provide a more robust shape to the algorithm (there may be extremes unconsidered), however, I am sure it works for the majority of cases. However, with the outline I provided, I am sure it will serve as a good starting point for you to tweak it according to your real data. Nonetheless, if you have any problem with the implementation, don't hesitate to reach out.
Having said this, I hope this helped... And may the code be with you!
NOTE: The order of the if statements DO MATTER, since it rules out possible double matches and mismatches of the regex expressions.
